# posix_spawn() : Problem with error handling when using posix_spawn()

Tags: c++, c, linux, multiprocessing, posix

I am trying to use posix_spawn() to create a new child process.
After the child process starts, the caller process should continue running.

TLDR: Why is posix_spawn() returning 0(success) even when path to child executable is invalid(does not exist)? How to correctly detect error in this case and any other cases where posix_spawn has actually failed but returns success?

I tried the following code.

```
/* The CALLER process*/
int main(int argc, char *argv) {
    int status, pid;

    printf("CALLER - Start\n");

    char *args[] = {"/home/<user>/child_exec", NULL};

    status = posix_spawn(&pid, args[0], NULL, NULL, args, environ);
    printf("Status: %d; PID: %d\n", status, pid);

    printf("CALLER - End\n");

    return 0;
}
```

```
/* The CHILD process */
int main() {
    printf("From CHILD\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the caller program with path to correct child executable, it runs as expected. The status of posix_spawn is 0 and the string from child process gets printed.

```
CALLER - Start
Status: 0; PID: 5110
CALLER - End
From CHILD
```

Now when I run the same program with an invalid child executable path(For example /home/user/child_exec123), it still returns status 0 even though the child process has not executed.

```
CALLER - Start
Status: 0; PID: 5251
CALLER - End
```

For this case where child path does not exist, I could just check existence of file before calling posix_spawn().
But what if there are other errors like these where posix_spawn() actually failed but returns 0? How do I find if there were some errors?

Comment: Curiously the implementation in IBM's AIX is sane -- it returns a failure in case of e.g. the executable file does not exist. I was very hopeful (for LINUX) that finally there is no need anymore to clone the calling process just to waste the results immediately after. But for some reason which eludes me, this is still standard practice in the year 2021!

Answer (score 3):

From the man page (in particular the second paragraph):

```
RETURN VALUE
       Upon successful completion, posix_spawn() and posix_spawnp() place  the
       PID  of  the  child process in pid, and return 0.  If there is an error
       before or during the fork(2), then no child is created, the contents of
       *pid are unspecified, and these functions return an error number as de‐
       scribed below.

       Even when these functions return a success status,  the  child  process
       may still fail for a plethora of reasons related to its pre-exec() ini‐
       tialization.  In addition, the exec(3)  may  fail.   In  all  of  these
       cases, the child process will exit with the exit value of 127.
```

You'll need to use one of the `wait*` functions to check the result of your child process.  This would be a good idea anyway, since otherwise you'd have a zombie.

Comment: But since wait* functions are blocking calls, how can I continue running the caller process while child process is running? I don't want to wait for the child to complete because the child could take a long time to complete.

Comment: `waitpid` takes options.  The one you want is `WNOHANG`.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried writing this if status returned by posix_spawn() is 0: `rc = waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);`. But waitpid is returning 0 even when child file path is wrong. It gives proper error if I sleep for 2 seconds before calling waitpid. How do I get rid of sleep and still be able to catch the error?

Comment: You're at the mercy of the scheduler, since there's no guarantee when your child process will try to call `execve`.  I'm not aware of any event you could wait for that would tell you the process has successfully executed (`SIGCHLD` would tell you it stopped, but that's stopped for any reason).

Comment: Curiously the implementation in IBM's AIX is sane -- it returns a failure e.g. the executable file does not exist. I was very hopeful (for LINUX) that finally there is no need anymore to clone the calling process and waste the results immediately. But for some reason which eludes me, this is still standard practice in the year 2021!

Comment: @FrankPuck - By "clone the calling process" do you mean `fork`?  That should be a cheap call these days, since memory is marked copy on write; if you're not modifying memory, nothing has to get copied.

Comment: @StephenNewell fork() is cheap? Then why is it hanging when profiling a memory intensive application? I've seen people trying to avoid doing fork() by starting a service process at the very beginning and letting this service process do all the fork-execp controlled by a pipe. I don't understand LINUX gurus!

Comment: @FrankPuck - I've never seen `fork` as a bottleneck, but I'll readily admit I don't do much systems programming these days.  Try switching the program to use `vfork` (be careful of its requirements) or `clone`.  If that's still your bottleneck, seems like a great candidate for a question here.

Answer (score 3):

`posix_spawn` returns before child process start where incorrect path will be detected. So, any errors during start of child process you can check only by its exit value.

As described in [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_spawn.3.html):

> RETURN VALUE
>
> ```
>    Upon successful completion, posix_spawn() and posix_spawnp() place
>    the PID of the child process in pid, and return 0.  If there is an
>    error during the fork() step, then no child is created, the contents
>    of *pid are unspecified, and these functions return an error number
>    as described below.
>
>    Even when these functions return a success status, the child process
>    may still fail for a plethora of reasons related to its pre-exec()
>    initialization.  In addition, the exec(3) may fail.  In all of these
>    cases, the child process will exit with the exit value of 127.
> ```
>
> ERRORS
>
> ```
>    The posix_spawn() and posix_spawnp() functions fail only in the case
>    where the underlying fork(2), vfork(2) or clone(2) call fails;  in
>    these cases, these functions return an error number, which will be
>    one of the errors described for fork(2), vfork(2) or clone(2).
>
>    In addition, these functions fail if:
>
>    ENOSYS Function not supported on this system.
> ```